# Tcolorbox, xshift and symmetry of the box

Tags: tcolorbox

I added to my colorboxes the option to shift on the x axis.

Nevertheless one problem emerged : the box is doing something symmetrical and when I move it to the right, the left also goes towards the center, making the box really small. How to counter this effect ?

Here is the code (if something is still redundant, please tell me. I'm trying to know how to do MWE).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}%réglages des marges du document selon vos préférences ou celles de votre établissemant
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}% hauteur de l'entête

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}%extensions de l'ams pour les mathématiques
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%pour les entêtes et pieds de pages
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}%pour un document en français

\definecolor{viol}{RGB}{134,0,175}



\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
         top=0mm,
         bottom=0mm,
         right=0mm,
        %colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        %coltitle=red,
        before={\vspace{0.1cm}}, 
        after={\vspace{0.3cm}},     
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-.20\linewidth, yshift= -.5 mm},
        minipage boxed title=.15\linewidth,
        left skip={0.09\linewidth},
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        },   
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DEMONSTRATION
    SQ/.style={thmbox, coltitle=viol, colback=white!95!viol,  left skip={.12\linewidth},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{demo}{Démonstration}{thmbox,SQ}{theo}

\begin{document}

hi !


\begin{demo}{}{}
OH!
\end{demo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

moreover I have a subsidiary question: how can I move a little bit the square (that appears in the pdf document) ? I want it to be in the box and not half outside like it is currently.

Comment: I've removed much of the useless. Can you add a screenshot of the effect you want to delete?

Comment: I added the picture with arrows. And you see the square on the pciture

Comment: How do you move the box to the right? What is the code for this move?

Comment: attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-.20\linewidth, yshift= -.5 mm},
        minipage boxed title=.15\linewidth,

Comment: It does not move the box, it moves the title, here « Démonstration »

Comment: oh sorry I forget the line after : left skip={0.09\linewidth}. And actually the coefficient 0.09 is for all of them apart demonstration that has a redefinition in it :  left skip={.12\linewidth},

Comment: I do not understand your problem, if you move the left side of the box to the right, it is normal that it is smaller unless you widen it to the right.

Comment: mhm do you see the right arrow ? I don't want that the box ends before the right end of the page. I wanted the box to go a little bit on the right that I have some space on the left side of the page, but I don't want the box to shrink from the right side

Comment: When I replace the code `left skip={.12\linewidth}`, by `.09\linewidth`, the box does not shrink on the right side, only the left side is modified.

Comment: I don't understand what you are changing. What are replacing by what ? Because only .09\linewidth doesn't make any sense

Comment: When I replace the code `left skip={.12\linewidth}` by `left skip={\linewidth}` (or vice versa), it doesn't shrink the right side. The easiest way is for you to construct the question by clearly indicating the code that does not pose a problem, the code that poses a problem and a screenshot to support it.

Comment: firstly what you recommand do something really strange.... actually the word demonstration fill the whole page from left to right.  Secondly, I want the box to be shifted but not shrinked ! just to fill the space of the page. I don't have any problem with my code it's just it doesn't do what I want. I thought I was clear. Am I now?

Comment: I mean it's not black magic : look page 81 of the documentation https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf
It is written that leftskip just translate but here the effect is similar to leftright skip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up something because you use `thmbox` style within `SQ` style but they have the same option with different values, and then, again you defined a `\newtcbtheorem` using both of them.

I kept them separate, even if, for convenience, you can create a style with the option which are *the same* for both the styles and then use it for both `thmbox` and `SQ`, adding only the options which *differ* to each of them.

For the square symbol at the end of the text, I used `\qed` for `asmthm` and this option: `after upper={\hfill$\qed$}`.

I didn't change the rule setting (but it seems a bit messy to me, too) because I don't still understand which is the final look you want.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mwe}% <-- for testing purpose only, delete it

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}%réglages des marges du document selon vos préférences ou celles de votre établissemant
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}% hauteur de l'entête

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb, amsthm}%amsthm added

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%pour les entêtes et pieds de pages
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}%pour un document en français

\definecolor{viol}{RGB}{134,0,175}



\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        %colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        %coltitle=red,
        before={\vspace{0.1cm}}, 
        after={\vspace{0.3cm}},     
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-.20\linewidth, yshift= -.5 mm},
        minipage boxed title=.15\linewidth,
        left skip={0.09\linewidth},
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
            (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
            (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },   
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DEMONSTRATION
    SQ/.style={%thmbox,
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        colframe=white,
        colback=white!95!viol, 
        colbacktitle=white!95!viol,
        coltitle=viol, 
        before={\vspace{0.1cm}}, 
        after={\vspace{0.3cm}},      
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-.25\linewidth%, yshift= -.5 mm
        },
        minipage boxed title=.23\linewidth,
        after upper={\hfill$\qed$},
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        %boxed title style={left=0mm, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt},
        left skip={.25\linewidth},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, 
    number within=section]{demo}{Démonstration}{SQ}{theo}

\begin{document}
    hi !
    \blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only, delete it
    \begin{demo}{}{}
        OH!
    \end{demo}
    \blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only, delete it 
\end{document}
```

[image]